# Getting Error 404 When Access to XMLHttpRequest at https://olb2c.b2clogin.com/olb2c.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_si_olp/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

Tags: c#, angular, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I am using the MSAl-Angular for B2C sign In , Some time before redireting to login or sometime when It redirect back to my application throw error when library is accessing the Api.

https://olb2c.b2clogin.com/olb2c.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_si_olp/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

But Its working fine when I access the endpoint normally using browser.

Or If Hard refresh the browser Its work fine sometimes.

[image]

Here is the msal module config.

```
MsalModule.forRoot({
      clientID: environment.clientID,
      authority:
        environment.authority +
        '/' +
        environment.tenantName +
        '/' +
        environment.userFlow + '/',
      validateAuthority: false,
      redirectUri: environment.redirectUri,
      popUp: false,
      consentScopes: [environment.ApiScope],
      protectedResourceMap: [
        [environment.ApiUrl, [environment.ApiScope]],

      ],
      level: LogLevel.Verbose,
      logger: loggerCallback,
      piiLoggingEnabled: true,
    })
```

```
environment = {
  production: false,
  ApiUrl: 'https://localhost:5001',
  ApiApplicationId: 'EEEB9D99-A5B3-4ECA-926C-2EAA4D472AAC',
  clientID: 'AAFCCDB8-7E5D-4873-96A8-80EA1D91568C',
  authority: 'https://olb2c.b2clogin.com',
  redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200',
  tenantName: 'ol.onmicrosoft.com',
  userFlow: 'B2C_1_SI_OLP',
  ApiScope: 'https://ol.onmicrosoft.com/olApi/access_as_external',
  userAccessGroups: [
    '499FA38D-50BE-4DFC-BC50-5497C9EA5CE1' // object .
  ],

};
```

Comment: Hi @mohi. Should `environment.tenantName` be set to `olb2c.onmicrosoft.com`?

Comment: Hi @ChrisPadgett It is already, Actuallly sometimes It work after refresh.

Comment: @mohi, Is it reproing consistently?